# Android Multiple seekbar in expandable listview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, runnable, seekbar

I have expandable `ListView` with cds as a groups and tracks as a children. Each child has `TextView`, `ImageButton`(playButton) and `SeekBar`.

Now when I clicked one of the playButtons I want to get access to related seekBar.

My problem is that I have global `SeekBar` and I can't get the right `SeekBar` object to set my Runnable object correctly. So when I have for example 3 children, I click the first play button, but the third `SeekBar` is starting.

I have no idea how to resolve it. Any suggestions? This code is in `getChildView()` method.

```
SeekBar sb_songProgress;
iv_trackRowIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {

            int song = l_cds.get(groupPosition).getTracks().get(childPosition).getTrackID();
            if(ArtistCardActivity.mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                ArtistCardActivity.mediaPlayer.stop();

            ArtistCardActivity.mediaPlayer.newTrack(song);
            int finalTime = ArtistCardActivity.mediaPlayer.getDuration();
            sb_songProgress.setMax((int) finalTime);
            sb_songProgress.setClickable(false);
            updateProgress(sb_songProgress);
        }
    });


public void updateProgress(SeekBar sb)
{
    int timeElapsed = ArtistCardActivity.mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    sb_songProgress.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);
    durationHandler.postDelayed(updateSeekBarTime, 100);
}

Runnable updateSeekBarTime = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {

        int timeElapsed = ArtistCardActivity.mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        //set seekbar progress
        sb_songProgress.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);
        durationHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the ViewHolder pattern (see [here](http://ocddevelopers.com/2014/extend-baseadapter-instead-of-arrayadapter-for-custom-list-items/), section "Overriding BaseAdapter"), then you will be able to handle seekbar progress with ViewHolder this way:

```
myHolder.sb_songProgress.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);
```

Hope it'll work